# Returning a json object from WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I can't seem to get the client to recognize json that I'm trying to return from my api.

Server code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Client value)
{
    LoginResult result = new LoginResult();
    var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);

    return response;
}
```

The client code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:/api/Login",
    data: JSON.stringify(client),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data){
        if(data.Message == "error")
        {
            alert("Error when logging in.");
            return;
        }

        alert("Login worked. Your token is " + data.Token + ". And you'll log into " + data.GameServerAddress + " on port " + data.GameServerPort;

        $("#loginUsername").val("");
        $("#loginPassword").val("");
    },
    error: function(jqXhr, exception){
        alert("There was an error logging on: " + jqXhr.status)
    }
});
```

It goes into the api call as I'm stepping through it and if I return just a string it's fine. But when I try returning an object on the client I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

In my WebApiConfig.cs I have:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

I also tried:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new RequestHeaderMapping("Accept", "text/html", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, true, "application/json"));
```

but neither of them worked. What am I missing? Every post about this says to use HttpResponseMessage and that this should work.

Comment: First Check, this method return proper data or not using postman or any other tool

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion problem with your code is

```
LoginResult result = new LoginResult();
```

You have not assigned any of its properties. Basically result dont have anything in it.

```
var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
```

Try assigning few properties.

For enforcing JSON response you can add below in global.asax

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Comment: Sorry, I do assign values I just didn't show that here.